# Stopping outside damage from active outside loo overflow pipe

Tags: plumbing, overflow

Why is  the outside WC cistern overflow pipe almost never plumbed so that it does not trickle over the brickwork, thereby eroding the mortar and causing damp bricks? Since cisterns overflow levels can be recurrent problems why not make the outside spout long enough to prevent trickling over the brickwork?

Answer (score 0):

It's just what happens when you have too many subcontractors. Details get ignored. Your question is a pet peeve of mine as well.

Personally, I'd add a collector and downspout, when it's my job. Over time, prevents the side of your building from looking like an abandoned mess.